# Build input file cannot be found: After Creating Bridging Header

Tags: objective-c, swiftui, file-not-found, bridging-header, pch

I add some Objective-C libraries to my SwiftUI project using bridging header, Now am facing an error:

*Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/.../../QPos-iOS/QPos-iOS-Bridging-Header'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it?*

**Steps That I have tried:**

- Create a Bridging Header File and (Import Objective-C files in Bridging Header File.)
- Target -> Build Settings -> Swift Compiler - General -> Ojbective-C Bridging Header (Put Bridging Header Path here)
- Precompile Bridging Header: Yes
- Clean Project.
- Delete Derived Data
- Restart Xcode
- Restart Machine.

but no luck, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hi author, did you fix that? I have the same problem too